# how to order products in related.phtml and item.phtml by specific attribute?

Tags: magento-enterprise, attributes, collection, sorting, product-relations

related.phtml is in

```
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/targetrule/catalog/product/list/related.phtml
```

I wanted to order the products by sku  in `app/code/core/Enterprise/targetRule/Block/Product/Abstract.php` we have a `getItemcollection` which will be used in related.phtml and it is so weird that it gets a position behavior and the position behavior is abstract protected and I cannot understand it, more over I tried to write a function to sort the $this->_items array by sku but the problem is that it's data is protected and I don't know how to call it

here is what I did in abstract.php:

```
public  function orderProductItemsByModel()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_items)) {
            if ($this->isShuffled()) {
                // shuffling assoc
                $ids = array_keys($this->_items);
                shuffle($ids);
                $items = $this->_items;
                $this->_items = array();
                foreach ($ids as $id) {
                    $this->_items[$id] = $items[$id];
                }
            } else {

           usort($this->_items, "sort_by_sku");
            }
            $this->_sliceItems();
        }
        return $this->_items;
    }
function sort_by_sku($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["data"]["sku"], $b["data"]["sku"]);
}
```

the problem is `$a["data"]["sku"]` I think I cannot get the data if you have idea about getData() function would you please let me know what i should use?

so it is not working here is print_r of $this->_items:

```
Array
(
    [3446] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object
        (
[_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 44444
                    [entity_type_id] => 4
                    [attribute_set_id] => 4
                    [type_id] => simple
                    [sku] => BC4R
```

I don't know id I should change item.phtml or I went my way correct

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can loop through them and then sort them I didn't want to do that because the sort function is more neat and fast but I had not any choice so I used for loops:

```
  public  function orderProductItemsByModel()
{
    if (!is_null($this->_items)) {
        if ($this->isShuffled()) {
            // shuffling assoc
            $ids = array_keys($this->_items);
            shuffle($ids);
            $items = $this->_items;
            $this->_items = array();
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $this->_items[$id] = $items[$id];
            }
        } else {
            $newarray=array();
            foreach ($this->_items as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $k=> $v)
                {
                    if($newarray[$key]=="")
                    $newarray[$key]  = $v['sku'];

                }
                    }
                    asort($newarray);
                foreach ( $newarray as $k=>$v)
                $keys[]=$k;
                $result=array();
        foreach($keys as $k=>$v) {
            $result[$v] = $this->_items[$v];
            }
                $this->_items=$result;
        }
        $this->_sliceItems();
    }
    return $this->_items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not be fooled by a programmer, this does NOT require custom programming. Sorting products by attributes is a common problem with a very simple solution.

**Here's how you add a custom attribute to the sortable options for customers**

1. Step 1 – Login to your Administration
2. Step 2 – Go to the Manage Attributes page
3. Step 3 – Locate the Attribute that you wish to sort by
4. Step Four – Set the Attribute to be used for sorting

Once the Attribute options page comes up for you, scroll to the very bottom. It’s here that you’ll find the option to set this attribute to be used for sorting in the product listings pages. Change the drop down’s option to “Yes” and save the attribute.

- Instructions have been pulled from the [Magento Support Center](http://magentosupport.help/knowledgebase/how-do-i-sort-products-by-a-custom-attribute/).

**Here's how to make that option a default**

Once you have got the attribute to show up, you will need to set it as default. You can load the specific category options or you can load the websites global configurations, depending on how default you would like to make the option. In either of these sections the default sorting option is pretty easy to find.

Comment: thank you but I wanted to be able to sort by many of them like rice,sku,.. will it provide me a combobox to refresh the website? II don't think so I wrote it manually

Comment: Yes it will also display in the sorting drop down box, so the users can choose how they want to sort.

Comment: I changed the price attribute sorting to yes but nothing happened but if it really is there it is absolutely amazing!

Comment: maybe because of custom theme I am not seeing anything

Comment: The themes are not normally involved in the collection creation and management. Unless somebody coded something that they shouldn't have, this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

magento uses magic functions, try using `getData()` to get `_data:protected`, 
example:

```
$data = $variable->orderProductItemsByModel();

print_r($data->getData);
```

Comment: but I should use something like $this->_items->getData() which will not work